# the element <projectreference> beneath element project is unrecognized

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

this is the error i am facing while adding the project reference to the .csproj file
, I am developing CRUD using ASP.net core + react js by taking help of microsoft learn here is the link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022

[project reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5i3i3.png)

[error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J54C5.png)

i am facing this issue can anyone help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgafB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change your .csproj file like below, the issue could be fixed.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\FootBallManagement_reactjs\FootBallManagement_reactjs.esproj">
      <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```